# Formula won't calculate or increment

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

In the following code, my formula apply as text and won't calculate. Also, Autofill won't increment cell number. I also tried with ActiveCell.Value

```
Dim RowCount As Variant
Dim VRowStartNoMember As Variant
Dim FirstBlankCell As String
Windows("Compliancy_Previous.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Previous").Select
RowCount = Range(("F1"), Range("F1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    
    Range("A2").Select
    If IsEmpty(Range("A2").Value) = False Then
    Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
    VRowStartNoMember = ActiveCell.Row
    FirstBlankCell = "F" & VRowStartNoMember
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FirstBlankCall,Import!A:E,2,0),"""")"
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":A" & RowCount)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the VBA variable FirstBlankCell in the formula, but you're embedding the variable name in the string instead of concatenating it.

Try this:

```
Dim RowCount As Variant
Dim VRowStartNoMember As Variant
Dim FirstBlankCell As String
Windows("Compliancy_Previous.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Previous").Select
RowCount = Range(("F1"), Range("F1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    
    Range("A2").Select
    If IsEmpty(Range("A2").Value) = False Then
    Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
    VRowStartNoMember = ActiveCell.Row
    FirstBlankCell = "F" & VRowStartNoMember
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & FirstBlankCell & ",Import!A:E,2,0),"""")"
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":A" & RowCount)
```

I think you may have other issues with the code however (hard to tell what you're trying to do), so please leave a comment if you encounter further problems and we can work through it.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks you !